# asp.net mvc some models were added during the migration

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

So I created several models in the project that I'm working on. But several models were not included on the migration class. So those models were not added to the database after running the Update-Database on the Package Manager Console. It is the initial migration/fresh database so I do not know where the conflict is.

I do not know where the error is or why it did not include all the models?

Kindly help me. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you forgot to include them to your DbContex?

Comment: ah I see, ok thank you so much.. yes I forgot to add them in my DBcontext.